# How to use the slot append of v-slider in render function?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

As we all know, we can use scopedslots to
replace the slot 'item' of v-select or the slot 'thumb-label' of v-slider like this way:

```
scopedSlots: {
    item: (props) => {
        if (this.$scopedSlots.item) {
            return this.$scopedSlots.item({
                test: 'works',
                item: props.item
            })
        }
    }
},
```

So we can use slot to replace the component's item's appearance.

But when we want to replace the 'append' slot of vuetify's v-slider on the some way,it doesn't work:

```
scopedSlots: {
    append: (props) => {
        if (this.$scopedSlots.append) {
            return this.$scopedSlots.append({
                test: 'works',
                item: props.item
            })
        }
    }
},
```

Is it different to a normal slot and a scoped slot .

If we use it in template，we just use v-slot:append to replace the slot's appearance：

```
<v-slider>
    <template v-slot:append>
        works
    </template>
</v-slider>
```

How to use this slots in a render function?
https://codepen.io/radiorz/pen/BaQeBOj

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question.
can you provide a codepen and some examples of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi,@JoelFilipeProençaRodrigues , I just want to use the slot(append) of vuetify's v-slider in vue2's render function, do you know how to do it?  the scopedslots can replace some slots but others didnt work,I dont know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuetify only generates the `append` slot if [it finds `append` or `append-outer` in `$slots`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dc19b82/packages/vuetify/src/components/VTextField/VTextField.ts#L259), but Vue only copies `scopedSlots` into `$slots` when the [value has a `proxy` property](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/2b93e86aa1437168476cbb5100cfb3bbbac55efa/src/core/vdom/helpers/normalize-scoped-slots.js#L74), which is an internal flag set [for `v-slot`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0603ff695d2f41286239298210113cbe2b209e28/src/core/instance/render-helpers/resolve-scoped-slots.js#L18).

A hacky workaround is to set this `proxy` flag on the `scopedSlots.append` value:

```js
const makeSlot = fn => {
  fn.proxy = true // workaround to copy into $slots
  return fn
}

const SliderWithSlot = {
  name: "SliderWithSlot",
  props: {},
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement("v-slider", {
      scopedSlots: {
        append: makeSlot(() => createElement('span', 'hello world')),
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ZEeEaXR?editors=1010)