# Vue render function - non-scoped slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-render-function

The [docs for the render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Slots) give an example of how to convert a scoped `v-slot` from a template

```html
<div><child v-slot="props"><span>{{ props.text }}</span></child></div>
```

to a render function:

```js
render: function (createElement) {
  return createElement('div', [
    createElement('child', {
      // pass `scopedSlots` in the data object
      // in the form of { name: props => VNode | Array<VNode> }
      scopedSlots: {
        default: function (props) {
          return createElement('span', props.text)
        }
      }
    })
  ])
}
```

However, what if the `v-slot` is not scoped? What if the template you were trying to convert was instead like

```html
<div><child v-slot:slotName><span>...</span></child></div>
```

(where I've also used a non-default slot named `slotName`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the Vue 2 version. Since 2.6.0+, Vue treats all slots the same, exposing them on [scopedSlots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-scopedSlots) no matter whether they are scoped or not.

> All `$slots` are now also exposed on `$scopedSlots` as functions. If you work with render functions, it is now recommended to always access slots via `$scopedSlots`, whether they currently use a scope or not. This will not only make future refactors to add a scope simpler, but also ease your eventual migration to Vue 3, where all slots will be functions.

So this should work:

```js
render: function (createElement) {
  return createElement('div', [
    createElement('child', {
      // pass `scopedSlots` in the data object
      // in the form of { name: props => VNode | Array<VNode> }
      scopedSlots: {
        slotName: function (props) {  // or function ()
          return createElement('span', props.text)
        }
      }
    })
  ])
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MichalLevy/354w1qv8/9/)

Comment: Note for Vuetify (v2) users - a workaround is needed for Vuetify components' non-scoped slots: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67412844/3217306